Can I provide callback from frontend (react) to backend and create API endpoint in react?
I develop service which will use ML for create response. So we can wait for response for about several seconds. So it's quite long time and I need not to block my frontend while waiting for response.
I develop my ped project and I'm newer in programming, so facing with such problem (wait for long response) for the first time. So how can I build architecture in my project, to solve this task?
One way I've found that I can send from frontend my request (it'll be simple string) and with this I'll send unique API endpoint (generate it with userId and queryId: http/.../query/{userId}/{queryId}) and the create endpoint with this url in frontend.
When response will be prepared my ApiGateway will send it to provided endpoint. So as a result, it turns out that the backend will send a ready response to the frontend, and this api will listen to the frontend.
I came to this approach, beacuse I have ApiGateway on the server and as I understood, I shouldn't block this ApiGateway by opening websocket connection or something like this. Because when some client open connection with server another client won't be able to connect to server.
As a result, I have the problem that I have a server that inherently (due to working with ML) will take a long time to process requests. At the same time, I need to somehow think about the moment when sending a request from the client (frontend) so that the client, while waiting for its long response, frees up the ability to connect to the server of other clients
I do programming unprofessionally and do not work anywhere, but now I'm just working on my project. Therefore, perhaps my question may sound stupid, but I hope that someone can help me, I'll be grateful for any help
My current architecture looks like here:

client (frontend on react) send request to backend (ApiGateway - Asp Net minimal API)
ApiGateway check the query and then send it through kafka to ML
One of services get the response from ML, handle it and send to ApiGateway through kafka
ApiGateway needs to send this response to client -- how to do that? - or maybe I need to restructure my logic?

So as you see ApiGateway just forwards requests, and so in theory can handle requests from multiple clients

The "correct" way to do this from a HTTP standpoint is to return a HTTP 102 response from the endpoint until the ML processing is complete and the response delivered to that endpoint.  Websockets obviously could "solve" this, at the cost of a higher connectivity requirement.

Client requests through API gateway
API Gateway provisions an endpoint url and sends the request through kafka (passing in the endpoint so it knows how to retrieve the payload)
API Gateway returns a "Continue" message to client (202) with the URL for the endpoint
3.1 Client begins polling endpoint, receiving a HTTP 102 response until it's complete
Service gets response from ML, fulfills the endpoint (this will require some kind of storage, probably a cache like Redis or similar)
API Gateway (or backing service) returns the fulfilled response and sends it when the client next polls

